# How prove this $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+4}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory

for any postive integer $n$ ,show that
$$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+4}$$ is irrational

I guess this following is also true
$$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+3}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+k},\forall k\ge 2,k\in N^{+}$$
is irrational?

Comment: By "$\forall k \in N^+$", are you including $k = 1$?

Comment: Hello,$k\ge 2$,mean that at least two term,

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956415/is-x1-frac1n-1-x1-frac1n-always-irrational

Comment: The difference between two perfect squares is atleast $4$, so one of $\sqrt{n+1},\sqrt{n+2},\sqrt{n+3},\sqrt{n+4}$ is non-square for $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's prove this for general $k\geq 2$.

First, note that "square roots have no unexpected linear relationships" (http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/)

This theorem is saying that for all $n_i$ distinct positive square-free integers, and all $a_i$ integers, there cannot be a linear relationship
$$
\sum_i a_i \sqrt{n_i} = 0$$

Now suppose that $\sum \sqrt{n+k}$ is rational, and equal to $p/q$ with $p, q \in \Bbb{N}^+$.  Then multiply through by q, and write $a'_i = q a_i$.  We also observe that for $k \geq 2$, there are is at least one square-free integer among $n+1, n+2$.  Then
after subtracting off $p$ (which cannot affect the rationallity of the sum)and re-writing any non-square-free term $a'_i \sqrt{n_i = r^2 m_i}$ as $(ra'_i\sqrt{m_i})$, we can apply the above theorem, which says that the sum of those square roots cannot be $0$, so the original sum could not be $p/q$.