# Prove that $\sqrt{10} - \sqrt6 - \sqrt5 + \sqrt3$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, radicals, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

I tried the methods shown in [Can $\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{m}$ be rational if neither $n,m$ are perfect squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares) but I cannot extend them well into 4 numbers.

Comment: $\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{5} = \sqrt{5}\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)$ and $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)$ so your expression can be rewritten as $(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3})\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)$.  Does this help?

Comment: If you can prove that $a=4\sqrt{30}-6\sqrt{15}-16\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, then you're done, since $\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{a+24}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\sqrt{m_1}+\sqrt{m_2}+ \cdots + \sqrt{m_n}$ is Irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126255/sqrtm-1-sqrtm-2-cdots-sqrtm-n-is-irrational)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt6+\sqrt5$ and $b=\sqrt{10}+\sqrt3$. You want to show that $b-a\notin\mathbb Q$.

Notice that
$$
\begin{align*}
a^2&=11+2\sqrt{30}\\
b^2&=13+2\sqrt{30}
\end{align*}
$$
hence 
$$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)=2$$
and $b+a=\frac2{b-a}$.

Now if $b-a\in\mathbb Q$, then also $b+a=\frac2{b-a}\in\mathbb Q$ and 
$$b=\frac{(b-a)+(b+a)}2\in\mathbb Q,$$
a contradiction. (To prove that $b$ is irrational you can use methods from the thread you linked.)

Answer (score 4):

$$\alpha=\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3} = \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{3}\right)$$
Hence:
$$ \alpha^2 = \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\left(8-2\sqrt{15}\right)$$
and since $\sqrt{15}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $\alpha^2$ is not a rational number, hence $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.