# Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational. Generalise this.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading R. Courant & H. Robbins' [*"What is Mathematics: An Elementary Approach to Ideas and Methods"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195105192) for fun. I'm on page $60$ and $61$ of the second edition. There are three exercises on proving numbers irrational spanning these pages, the last is as follows.

> **Exercise $3$:** Prove that $\phi=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational. Try to make up similar and more general examples.

### **My Attempt:**

> **Lemma:** The number $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. *(This is part of Exercise 2.)*

*Proof:* Suppose $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=r$ is rational. Then
$$\begin{align}
2&=(r-\sqrt{3})^2 \\
&=r^2-2r\sqrt{3}+3
\end{align}$$ is rational, so that
$$\sqrt{3}=\frac{r^2+1}{2r}$$ is rational, a contradiction. $\square$

Let $\psi=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Then, considering $\phi$,
$$\begin{align}
5&=(\phi-\psi)^2 \\
&=\phi^2-2\psi\phi+5+2\sqrt{6}.
\end{align}$$

I don't know what else to do from here.
My plan is/was to use the **Lemma** above as the focus for a contradiction, showing $\psi$ is rational somehow.

Please help :)

### Thoughts:

The "try to make up similar and more general examples" bit is a little vague.

---

The question is not answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1126255/104041) as far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you know anything about extensions of fields?

Comment: @Wolfram Unlikely, from the chosen reference ...

Comment: @Wolfram A little bit, yes, from Galois Theory and Algebraic Number Theory, but I'm approaching this from Elementary Number Theory, as the title of the book suggests.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelBurr :)

Comment: You can work out the minimal polynomial of your number, it turns out to be $x^8 - 40 x^6 + 352 x^4 - 960 x^2 + 576$ (I did it with Wolfram Alpha, could be done by hand with some effort).

Comment: Using some well known results from field theory one sees that $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ are members of some basis of $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}]$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of elements of this basis, so it is irrational.

Comment: You write "The "try to make up similar and more general examples" bit is a little vague." The question is quite interesting. You may find the following conclusion: "The sum of an arbitrary nimber square roots of prime numbers is irrational." Try to imagine a few other theorems. The lemma in @N.S.'s answer seems to be the most general.

Comment: If it were rational, then it would be an integer (since it is an algebraic integer)…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Hint:**

Assume by contradiction that $\psi=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational. Then 
$$(\psi-\sqrt{5})^2=(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2 \\
\psi^2-2\sqrt{5}\psi+5=5+2\sqrt{6} \\
\psi^2=2\sqrt{6} +2\sqrt{5}\psi\\
$$

Square it one more time, and you reach the contradiction.

For the general case, here is a nice trivial solution from Kvant: prove the following lemma:

**Lemma** If $a_1,a_2,..,a_k$ are distinct integers $\geq 2$, none of which is divisible by a square, and $b_1,..,b_n$ are integers such that 
$$b_1\sqrt{a_1}+...+b_n\sqrt{a_n} \in \mathbb Q$$
then $b_1=...=b_n=0$.

**Proof:** Do induction by the number $m$ of primes which divide $a_1...a_n$.

The inductive step $P(m)\Rightarrow P(m+1)$ is done by contradiction: move all terms for which $a_k$ is divisible by the $p_{m+1}$ on one side, everything else on the other side and square, to end in the case $P_m$.

Comment: It should be +2 sqrt 5 psi

Comment: The Lemma is already proved [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242) more generally

Answer (score 15):

Okay, if $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=r\in\mathbb Q$, then:
$$(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2=(r-\sqrt{5})^2$$
$$2+2\sqrt6+3=r^2-2\sqrt5 r+5$$
$$2\sqrt6=r^2-2\sqrt5 r$$
Square this once again and you obtain that $\sqrt5$ is rational, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you! $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 6):

We assume we have
$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=\frac{m}{n}$$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$. We write
$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\frac{m}{n}-\sqrt{5};$$
squaring, we have
$$2\sqrt{6}=\frac{m^2}{n^2}-2\frac{m}{n}\sqrt{5};$$
and squaring once again then simplifying, we arrive at
$$5\frac{n}{m}+\frac{m}{4n}-6\frac{n^3}{m^3}=\sqrt{5}.$$

This is a contradiction, since we have on the left only rational numbers and on the right side an irrational number.

Answer (score 3):

Use these properties of rational numbers:

1. If $x$ is rational then $x^2$ is also rational.
2. Sum of a rational number and an irrational number is irrational.

Let's suppose $x = \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is rational. Then $x^2 = 5 + 2 \sqrt 6$ (which is irrational using the second property).

Using the first property, $x$ also becomes irrational.

Now using the second property we can say that since $x(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)$ is irrational, irrespective of whether $\sqrt 5$ is rational or irrational using the second property, the total sum will be irrational. Thus $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi. Your post could use some layout, you can read on the mathjax tutorial how to layout the math.

Comment: Cut him some slack, he's new. But he'll be expected to start doing it himself as time goes on.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the edit.I am new and I am trying to learn stuffs

Comment: "irrespective of whether $\sqrt{5}$ is rational or irrational using the second property, the total sum will be irrational", but the sum of two irrational is not always rational. Hence the second property will not be applicable here. If I am making a mistake then kindly inform me. (1 + $\sqrt{2}$) + (1 - $\sqrt{2}$) = 2

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution. Assume that $\alpha=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$. By quadratic reciprocity, there is some prime $p>b$ such that $3$ and $5$ are quadratic residues $\!\!\pmod{p}$ while $2$ is not. That implies that $\alpha$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{F}_p$ with degree $2$, since $\sqrt{2}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{K}$ but belongs to a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{K}$. On the other hand $b<p$ ensures that $b$ is an invertible element $\!\!\pmod{p}$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$, contradiction.

This proof has a straightforward generalization: the sum of the square roots of some prime numbers is never a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

Using the straightforward fact that the **sum of two (or more) algebraic integers is an algebraic integer** ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer#Facts)), one has the following very short argument: since $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}$ are algebraic integers, their sum $A=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ must be also. Hence if $A$ is rational, it must be an integer. However, as a rudimentary estimate of the three square roots shows, we have $5 < A < 6$: contradiction.