# $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

Tags: solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

I have used the following Theorems to prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

**Theorem 3.2)** Let $x$ be an integer. $x^2$ is odd if and only if $x$ is odd.

**Theorem 5.6)** If $x$ is a rational number and $y$ is an irrational number, then $x+y$ is irrational.

**Theorem 5.9)** Let $n$ be an integer. If $n^2$ is divisible by $3$, then $n$ is divisible by $3$.

The following is my proof.

---

The number $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

*Proof.* Suppose that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is a rational number. It follows that there exist an integer $p$ and a nonzero integer $q$ such that

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} = \frac{p}{q} \text{ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Because the number $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is a nonzero number, the number $\frac{p}{q}$ is nonzero.

Multiplying both sides of the above equation by $(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3})$, one obtains

\begin{align}
(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}) = \frac{p}{q}(\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}) \text{ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$}
\end{align}

By multiplying $-1$ on both sides of the above equation and making $\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{3} - \frac{p}{q}\sqrt{2}$ as the subject one obtains

\begin{align}
\frac{p}{q}\sqrt{3} - \frac{p}{q}\sqrt{2} = 1 \text{ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Squaring both sides of the above equation, one obtains

\begin{align}
5\frac{p^2}{q^2} - 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}\frac{p^2}{q^2} = 1 \text{ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$}
\end{align}

By multiplying both sides of the above equation by $\frac{q^2}{2p^2}$, one obtains

\begin{align}
\frac{5}{2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{q^2}{2p^2} \text{ for some $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \ne 0$}
\end{align}

To show that $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, suppose that $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ is on the contrary rational.

It follows that there exist an integer $r$ and a nonzero integer $s$ such that

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{r}{s} \text{ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Assuming that $r$ and $s$ has no common factor. Squaring both sides of the above equation one obtains

\begin{align}
2 \cdot 3 = \frac{r^2}{s^2} \text{ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Making $\frac{r^2}{3}$ as the subject, one obtains

\begin{align}
\frac{r^2}{3} = 2s^2 \text{ for some $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Because the number on the $RHS$ of the above equation is an integer, $r^2$ is divisible by $3$. It follows from **Theorem 5.9)** that $r$ is divisible by $3$.

Thus,

\begin{align}
r = 3i \text{ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}

Substituting the above equation into the equation $\frac{r^2}{3} = 2s^2$ one obtains

\begin{align}
3i^2 = 2s^2 \text{ for some $i,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Because the number on the $RHS$ of the above equation is even, $3i^2$ must be even. Since $3$ is odd, the factor $2$ must be from the number $i^2$. Therefore, $i^2$ is even. It follows from **Theorem 3.2)** that $i$ is even.

Thus,

\begin{align}
i = 2u \text{ for some $i,u \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}

Substituting the above equation into the equation $r = 3i$, one obtains

\begin{align}
r = 2 \cdot 3u \text{ for some $u \in \mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}

Substituting the above equation into the equation $2 \cdot 3 = \frac{r^2}{s^2}$ and making $s^2$ as the subject, one obtains

\begin{align}
s^2 = 2 \cdot 3 u^2 \text{ for some $s,u \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $s \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Because $s^2$ is even and divisible by $3$, it follows from **Theorem 3.2)** and **Theorem 5.9)** that $s$ is even and divisible by $3$.

Thus,

\begin{align}
s = 2 \cdot 3 v \text{ for some $v \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $v \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Substituting the equation $r = 2 \cdot 3u$ and the equation $s = 2 \cdot 3 v$ into the equation $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{r}{s}$, one obtains

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{2 \cdot 3u}{2 \cdot 3 v} \text{ for some $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $v \ne 0$}
\end{align}

Because $r$ and $s$ have common factors, one obtains a contradiction with the assumption that $r$ and $s$ have no common factor.

Hence, the number $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Since on the equation $\frac{5}{2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{q^2}{2p^2}$ the number $\frac{5}{2}$ is rational and $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ is irrational, by **Theorem 5.6)**, the number $\frac{5}{2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. However, because $\frac{p}{q}$ is a nonzero rational number, the number $\frac{q^2}{2p^2}$ on the $RHS$ of the equation $\frac{5}{2} - \sqrt{2}\sqrt{3} = \frac{q^2}{2p^2}$ is a nonzero rational number.

Thus, one obtains a contradiction.

Therefore, the number $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

---

Is the proof correct?

---

**Reference**

Daepp, U. and Gorkin, P., 2011. *Reading, Writing, and Proving*. 2nd ed. pp.29, 54, 55.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2125853/104041)

Comment: $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is a root of $x^4-10x^2+1$, which has no rational roots per the rational root theorem

Comment: Shorter, but still similar: $5=(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)$ is rational. If one of its factors is rational, then so is the other. But they can't both be rational, since they differ by $2\sqrt 2$, which is irrational.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof in the original question is more work than is necessary to prove something so simple.

All you need to do is show that $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2$ is irrational${}^\dagger$, which amounts to showing that $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational, which you can prove in the same way you prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

$\dagger$ Note that $x^2$ irrational $\implies x\ $ is irrational. This is easy to see by considering the contrapositive.