# Prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

Note that my attempted method below is distinct from the solutions in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125853/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-is-irrational-generalise-this).

I also know this is generally true for $\sqrt p + \sqrt q + \sqrt r$ where $p,q,r$ are prime, but I am asking if my particular method works.

Prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Assume that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 = \frac pq$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb Z$, in lowest terms, with $q \neq 0$. Then at most one of $p$ and $q$ can be even.  Then

\begin{align*}
\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 &= \frac pq\\
\\
(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5)^2 &= \left(\frac pq \right)^2\\
\\
2(5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})&=\frac{p^2}{q^2}\\
\\
2q^2(5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})&=p^2
\end{align*}

which shows that $p^2$ is even, so $p$ is even and let $p=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. Substituting this we get

\begin{align*}
2q^2(5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})&=(2k)^2\\
\\
q^2(5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})&=2k^2\\
\\
q^2 &= 2 \left(\frac{k^2}{5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15}}\right),
\end{align*}
which shows as well that $q$ is even, a contradiction. Hence $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$ is irrational.

Comment: As $5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt {10} + \sqrt{15}$ is not an integer, we can not conclude $p^2$ is even.  Nor could we conclude $q^2 = 2\frac k{5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10}+\sqrt {15}}$ implies $q^2$ is even.

Comment: Ah, okay. That was the part I was unsure about.

Comment: It *would* imply that that $\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15}$ is rational.  You can repeat with letting $\sqrt 6 + \sqrt {10} +\sqrt {15} = \frac {p^2}{2q^2} - 5 = \frac mn$ and continue.  It would be *very* inefficient but it would eventually end.

Comment: One approach is to compute the minimal polynomial - it is the 3rd [Swinnerton-Dyer polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Swinnerton-DyerPolynomial.html) - and show that it is irreducible (well by definition minimal polynomials are irreducible).

Comment: More straightforward and short is if $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 = r\in \mathbb Q$ then $\sqrt 3+ \sqrt 5 = r-\sqrt 2$ and then square both sides to get $3+5 + 2\sqrt{15}=r^2-2r\sqrt 2 + 2$. Isolate one radical and square again and you get an equate with just one radical in it.  That implies that last radical is rational and you can easily prove it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational. Generalise this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125853/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt5-is-irrational-generalise-this). Please check if your question has already been asked before using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) or SearchOnMath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> $$2(5+\sqrt 6 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{15})=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$$

This step, you cannot conclude the LHS is an even integer.

You can try this: Assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=r_1$ be rational.

$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=r_1-\sqrt{5}\Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{6}=r_1^2-2\sqrt{5}r_1\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5}r_1=\frac{r_1^2}{2}=r_2 \\
\\
\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{6}=r_2-\sqrt{5}r_1\Leftrightarrow 6=r_2^2+5r_1^2-2r_1\sqrt{5}\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{5}=\frac{r_2^2+5r_1^2-6}{2r_1}$$

$\sqrt{5}$ is irrational , but RHS is rational, so you get contradictions.

Answer (score 3):

There are infinite primes of the form $p=120k+61$ by Dirichlet's theorem. For any of them we have that $3$ and $5$ are quadratic residues, since $p\equiv 1\pmod{15}$, while $2$ is not a quadratic residue since $p\equiv 5\pmod{8}$. Assume that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=\frac{a}{b}$ and take a prime $p$ of the previous form with $p> \max(5,b)$. Since $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=-1$ while $\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)=1$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ has degree $2$. In particular $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ cannot be an algebraic number with degree $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. a rational number.

*Alternative approach*. Always assuming $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}=q\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$ 8+2\sqrt{15}=(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2 = (q-\sqrt{2})^2 = (q^2+2)-2q\sqrt{2},$$
$$ 2\sqrt{15}+2q\sqrt{2} = (q^2-6),$$
$$ (60+8q^2) + 8q \sqrt{30} = (q^2-6)^2, $$
$$ \sqrt{30} = \frac{(q^2-6)^2-(60+8q^2)}{8q} $$
but the last line implies $\sqrt{30}\in\mathbb{Q}$ which we know not to be the case.

Both approaches can be easily extended for proving that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{p_k}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ for any collection of primes $p_k$.

Answer (score 2):

No. What if $5+\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{15} = \frac{17}{2}$? (I don't think it is, but you certainly haven't shown that it isn't.)

Comment: A better rational approximation of the value is 29/2.

Comment: I guess a better rational approximation in the sense of supplying an answer to the question would be $0$, whereupon we manifestly can tell nothing at all about $q$ :P

Comment: (But yes, that would be a minor quibble which the usual argument of $\sqrt{2}$'s irrationality also tends to sweep under the cover.)