# Prove that both $x+y$ and $xy$ are rational, under some conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

As a result of the answer I got for this question - [Irrational solutions to some equations in two variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954726/irrational-solutions-to-some-equations-in-two-variables/956670#956670) - I was wondering if the next statement is always true:

Let $x,y$ be **real, irrational** numbers such that $x+y\ne0$. 
And let $n_1,n_2,n_3$ be some positive integers (different from each other) such that $\gcd(n_1,n_2,n_3)=1$.

Prove (or find a counter example) that if: $$x^{n_1}+y^{n_1}$$ $$x^{n_2}+y^{n_2}$$ $$x^{n_3}+y^{n_3}$$ are all rational numbers, then also both: $$x+y$$  $$xy$$ have to be rational numbers.

Comment: You at least need $d= \gcd(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ to be $1$. Otherwise something like $x=\sqrt[d]{2},y=\sqrt[d]{3}$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: You are right, I'll edit it in a minute.

Comment: This holds for the triple $(2,3,4)$.

Comment: And for $(2,3,5)$... well, let's just say that this is of similar difficulty to your last problem.

Comment: I think this is true

Comment: The condition that $x+y$ and $xy$ are rational is equivalent to saying that they are the roots of a quadratic with rational coefficients ($z^2 - (x+y)z + xy$ in particular) and hence that, for some rational $p$ and $q$ that $x=p+\sqrt{q}$ and $y=p-\sqrt{q}$.

Comment: @mercio Why?  I am finding it very hard to have a good intuition about this problem.

Comment: I suspect that a necessary stepping stone is, if we let $f(n)=x^n+y^n$, there must be some algebraic relation between $f(n_1),f(n_2)$, and $f(n_3)$, since knowing two, the other can only take finitely many values - i.e. a polynomial $P(f(n_1),f(n_2),f(n_3))=0$. It's not obvious to me what this relation must be, since the only relation I know of is $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)-(xy)^af(b-a)$, but that introduces $(xy)^a$ as a variable, which is troublesome.

Comment: @Slade : my anecdotary evidence about all the $n1<n2<n3<10$ cases. Also the regularity of $[K(x^n+y^n,x^m+y^m) : K(x+y,xy)]$ which is $nm$ when one of them is even.

Comment: I meant $nm/2$ ...

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, the statement doesn't hold in general. For instance for $(n_1, n_2, n_3) = (2, 3, 8)$ we can choose
$$
x = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3} - 1 +\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{3}\right)
$$
and
$$
y = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3} - 1 -\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{3}\right).
$$
Now it's easy to see that $\gcd(2,3,8) = 1$, $x^2+y^2 = 2$, $x^3+y^3 = 2$ and $x^8+y^8 = 8$, and both numbers are irrational, but still
$$
x+y = \sqrt{3} - 1
$$
and
$$
xy = 1- \sqrt{3}
$$
are not rational.

Comment: Nicely constructed example.

Comment: I agree that this is easy to check (though, I confess I didn't), but how did you discover it to begin with?

Comment: I first chose, n1 and n2 to be as simple as possible, then sum of squares and cubes to be also easy to handle. Then I checked for other solutions for resulting system, and found those with Wolfram Alpha. Then I just checked the sum for other small powers and noticed that the 8th powers add up to integer.

Comment: Actually the OP has pushed his luck: the natural generalization of his previous question would have to consider three consecutive exponents.

Comment: @user26857 how do you figure that "the natural" generalization must do so?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Maybe because 4,5, and 6 are consecutive?

Comment: @user26857 I mean why that particular choice of generalization? Both your version and OP's version are generalizations of the previous question. One is obviously stronger than the other, but I don't see what criterion you're using to say that one is "more natural" than the other.

Comment: $\Bbb C(x^2+y^2,x^3+y^3,x^8+y^8) = \Bbb C(x+y,xy)$, but when you express $x+y$ (or $xy$) in terms of those $3$ quantities and evaluate with your example, you get $0/0$. I didn't think about that one happening lol.